# Converting to .h5 file

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have .index and .data files of a pre-trained model.I want to load the model and use it .I was not able to find a way to load them directly so I was thinking of first converting to .h5 first. How to convert to .h5 ?

I know that `model.load()` works for .h5 files .

Comment: There is an `h5py` module that can save and load .h5 files.  https://pypi.org/project/h5py/

Comment: @TimRoberts How?

Comment: How?  By using the `h5py` module.  Did you read any of the documentation?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi @Testdark123, It seems you have saved the model weights using `ModelCheckpoint` Callback where the weights will be saved in the form of Checkpoint files (.data, .index etc.). You can simply load these weights by putting the path of the folder where checkpoint files are stored(checkpoint_path) , in `model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)`. Please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_checkpoints_during_training) for more details. Thank you.